# GWT CellTable user controled width

Tags: gwt, celltable, dynamic-columns

Is there a way, after the construction of the CellTable, to allow the page's user to change the column width?
I am building a celltable where the user can add columns and many of them and i want him/her to have the ability to change the columns width not using a numeric form he has to give me when he constructs the column, but by using the mouse like in regular non web applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a discussion of this issue, which also includes a proposed solution:

https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6401